# Cucumber features are not being recognized by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, eclipse-plugin, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have installed Natural 0.7.6 version plugin from Eclipse Market and the installation was successful.
I tried Cucumber feature and Eclipse is not recognising the same.

After installing Natural 0.7.6, I created a "Features" package and added a file called "login.feature"
The keywords like Scenario, When, Given aren't getting highlighted.

```
Feature: Macys Login Feature

Scenario: Macys Login Test Scenario

Given User is already on Login Page
When title of login page is Macys
Then user enters Username
```

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using? Not all plugins compatible with all version of eclipse.

Comment: I am using Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)

Comment: According to plugin details it doesn't support 4.10.0 refer additional info on https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cucumber-eclipse-plugin. Supported Eclipse Versions:  2018-09 (4.9), Photon (4.8), Oxygen (4.7), Neon (4.6), Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4), Kepler (4.3), Juno (4.2, 3.8), Previous to Juno (<=4.1)

Comment: So do I need to downgrade my Eclipse version?

Comment: it's up to you, alternately you can use other plugin that supports the version you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because of the plug-in you installed not compatible with version of eclipse. You should check supported version on plugin page. I am using [qaf bdd editor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/qaf-bdd-editors) for eclipse and it works fine for me. It supports Kepler (4.3) or above up to latest and works well for feature file written in `gherkin` with cucumber step implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Even though it changes the icon of your file(see below OpenWebPage.Feeature) and it looks in green round, by default the editor remains the text editor

**Right click** with the file being open and **select Cucumber Editor**

[image]

Now the colors will automatically change, as now the editor is changed and would look like below

[image]

All credits too http://go-gaga-over-testing.blogspot.com/2014/10/eclipse-cucumber-plugin-syntax.html as i also faced the same problem and this helped me

Answer (score 2):

From the [Cucumber docs on using Eclipse](https://docs.cucumber.io/tools/java/#eclipse):

"Eclipse has the [Cucumber Eclipse plugin](https://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse/)"

Have you installed this plugin? (I don't use Eclipse so I'm not familiar with the plugin you've mentioned).

Comment: Yes I have installed Cucumber Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Cucumber eclipse plugin may not work with latest version of eclipse. Refer [plugin page on marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cucumber-eclipse-plugin), it reads Eclipse Versions: 
2018-09 (4.9), Photon (4.8), Oxygen (4.7), Neon (4.6), Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4), Kepler (4.3), Juno (4.2, 3.8), Previous to Juno (<=4.1).

Comment: I am using Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0). So that means Cucumber is not compatible with 4.10 eclipse version. So should I downgrade the Eclipse?

Comment: As I don't use Eclipse I can't give any advice on which Cucumber version works with which Eclipse plugin version. If the Exclipse (plugin) project has documentation / a support channel and/or issue tracker, I'd try checking there for which Cucumber versions are supported and possibly upvoting/creating an issue to make it compatible with newer versions of Cucumber.

Answer (score 2):

The way I found is
Go to any feature file->right click->open with->other->choose cucumber editor->and down check box "use it for all feature files"-> click on ok
Done all feature files will be in cucumber format